# Regarding the Challenge Problem in 3Blue1Brown's most recent video: Will $\binom{x}{4}+\binom{x}{2}+1=2^k$ for $x>10$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, p-adic-numbers

Link to the video here [with timestamp](https://youtu.be/YtkIWDE36qU?t=895)

In deriving the formula for regions of [Moser's Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas), it observed that the formula
$$
F(x)=\binom{x}{4}+\binom{x}{2}+1
$$
achieves values that are equal to powers of $2$ for $x\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,10\}$. The question then becomes: Do there exist any other values of $x$ such that $F(x)=2^k$ for some value of $k$ ?

---

I thought that it might be worthwhile to look at it from a $p$-adic perspective but hit a wall. I will show what I attempted regardless.
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{24}\left(x^4-6x^3+23x^2-18x+24\right)
$$
and now define
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^4-2x^3+\frac{23}{3}x^2-6x+8.
$$
Our question becomes equivalent to if there are any other $x,n$ such that $f(x)=2^n$.

If we solve out the modular congruence
$$
f(x)\equiv 0 \mod 2^4
$$
we can see that there are $8$ solutions ($2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13$), what I've seen is that for all $n\geq 4$, that
$$
f(x)\equiv 0\mod 2^n
$$
has exactly $8$ solutions (but I can't prove that). These $8$ solutions have been retrieved by "lifting" $4$ of the previous value $n$ solutions as well as keeping it as well. What I mean by this is that if $x^\*$ solves for $\mod 2^{n-1}$, then $x^\*$ and $x^\*+2^n$ solve for $\mod 2^n$, and four solutions $\mod 2^{n-1}$ are "dead" and do not lift. The reason we get two lifted solutions is that
$$
f'(x)\equiv 0 \mod 2
$$
for all values of $x$ (easy to show if you multiply both sides by $3$), which by a theorem that is not named in my Number Theory textbook shows that if $x^\*$ solves for $\mod 2^n$, then so will $x^\*+2^{n-1}$. As for why *exactly* $4$ solutions always seem to lift, I also do not know.

By calculating this equation for larger values of $n$, we can find our lift values seem to be converging to $4$ solutions in the $2$-adics
$$
\begin{align}
\ldots&110111100100_2 \\\\
\ldots&010000001010_2 \\\\
\ldots&011111000101_2 \\\\
\ldots&011001010011_2
\end{align}
$$

Funny thing is that you can see the $0,1,2,3,4,5,10$ all encoded in these solutions being lifted.

This is where I hit a wall (I've been going at this for a few hours so sorry if its a ramble), so it'd be interesting if anyone else had some insights into the problem

---

Specific Questions (in order of importance):

1. Does there exist any other solutions?
2. Are we guaranteed to have $8$ solutions to every modular congruence?
3. Do these lifted solutions converge to anything interesting?

Comment: @DavidRoberts totally forgot woopsies haha

Comment: Have you tried a Thue–Mahler solver?

Comment: @user471019 I've never heard of this, do you have a good resource that you like that I can use to learn?

Comment: For the original problem, you can look at the equation $y^2=\frac{1}{3}x^4-2x^3+\frac{23}{3}x^2-6x+8$ and $2y^2=\frac{1}{3}x^4-2x^3+\frac{23}{3}x^2-6x+8$. They all have finite number of integral solutions by a theorem of Seigel. Wolfram alpha gives a set of integer solutions, but I'm not sure it's guaranteed to be complete. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2y%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7Dx%5E4-2x%5E3%2B%5Cfrac%7B23%7D%7B3%7Dx%5E2-6x%2B8 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7Dx%5E4-2x%5E3%2B%5Cfrac%7B23%7D%7B3%7Dx%5E2-6x%2B8

Comment: What does "if there are infinite ," mean?  Your original question does not mention infinite anything, so why is it mentioned here? (And once again: What does the quote in my first sentence mean?)

Comment: @DanielAsimov Clearly "infinitely many" was intended.

Comment: @PeterWu yeah the list provided in the Wolfram Alpha solutions is missing two solutions $5,10$ unfortunately

Comment: Sean Eberhard: But OP states that it was the same as the original question, so if you're right it is *not* the same question. (Which now appears edited to remove the "infinite".)

Comment: @DanielAsimov I changed to "any other", it was a leftover from my first draft I didn't catch sorry

Comment: It does seem like there ought to be a simpler solution just based on Hensel's lemma, sort of along OP's reasoning. The given solutions $0, 1,2,3,4,5, 10$ each approximately lift to a 2-adic solution to $f(x) = 0$. Any other $x$ such that $f(x) = 2^n$ for some large $n$ would necessarily lift to one of those same $2$-adic solutions, which means that $x$ would be $2$-adically close to one of the known solutions.